# Function calculating maximum value in AT&T x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm trying to write this function called maximum which will return maximum value from a list of numbers, i want to use labels which can indicate where to start. When address (that I use for calculating where the next value is), will exceed list, function will jump to the end of the loop.

Unfortunately after assembling program and running it i get segmentation fault.

I'm asking to find mistake in my code.  I tried to use GDB debugger but still I couldn't.

```
.section .data
list_1:
 .long 5,3,6,2,7,78
list_2:
 .long 33,23,52,6,7,89,22,33,6
list_3:
 .long 22,33,10,45,6,34
end_list_3:

 .section .text

 .globl _start
 .globl maximum
_start:

 pushl list_2
 pushl list_1
 call maximum
 addl $8, %esp
 movl %eax, %ebx


 mov $1, %eax
 int $0x80
                        #maximum function: 1 param - location of first value
                        #                  2 param - location of last value+4
 .type maximum STT_FUNC
maximum:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp

 movl 8(%ebp),%ebx      # %ebx = location of first value
 movl 12(%ebp), %ecx    # %ecx location of last value + 4

 movl (%ebx), %eax      # %eax will store current highest value

 movl $0, %esi          # %esi will be our index

start_loop:
 incl %esi
 lea (%ebx,%esi,4), %edx
 cmpl %edx, %ecx
 je exit_loop
 movl (%ebx,%esi,4), %edi       #%edi is a current examined value
 cmpl %eax, %edi
 cmovg %edi, %eax
 jmp start_loop
exit_loop:

 movl %ebp, %esp
 popl %ebp
 ret
```

Comment: The assembly code is duplicated I think. Is is normal ?

Comment: What did the debugger tell you? Anyway, at&t syntax requires `$` sign for immediates so you already went wrong at `pushl list_2` because you want to push the address not the value. Same for `list_1` of course. There may be other mistakes too.

Comment: @Jester, That's it, now it's working good, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in pushing arguments, I wanted to push label addresses but was using:

```
pushl   list_2
pushl   list_1
```

list_1 and list_2 are treated as addresses to the value that will be pushed on the stack, so this was pushing a memory source operand not an immediate.

Instead, use:

```
pushl   $list_2
pushl   $list_1
```

After that small change the program is working as planned, now these 2 instructions pushes direct addresses: list_1 and list_2, which is what I wanted.

Thank you @Jérôme Richard and @Jester.

Comment: I believe you want `pushl $list_2` and `pushl $list_1`.

Comment: @fuz: yup, `push &list_1` is a syntax error.  I fixed this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a debugger to find why easily. I advise you to use gdb (especially using the `layout asm` and `ni` commands).

The segfault is located at this line:

```
    mov (%ebx), %eax
```

This is normal as the value stored in ebx is an integer (5) and not a valid pointer.
You probably wanted to use lea rather than movl in the following instructions:

```
    movl 8(%ebp),%ebx      # %ebx = location of first value
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx    # %ecx location of last value + 4
```

Comment: It's correct because I push addresses, and also i want load them into registers. After changing push list_1 to push $list_1 and push list_2 to push $list_2, the program is working as I wish. Can you supply some links that will acquaint me with gdb? It's also interesting how gdb was emphasizing the segfault in mov (%ebx), %eax.

Comment: Ok. For gdb, there is a lot of (mostly quite bad) tutorials for that on internet. You can start with [this one](https://ncona.com/2019/12/debugging-assembly-with-gdb/) or [this one](http://beej.us/guide/bggdb/).